# Selecting items using LinqtoEntities lambda C#

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, lambda

I am using Entity Framework code first technique in Visual Studio 2012
Here is my context

```
public class BakingWebContext : DbContext
{
        public DbSet<Recipe> Recipes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

I have a Category Class

```
public class Category
{
        [Key]
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string ImageUrl { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Recipe> Recipes { get; set; }

}
```

It contains a virtual collection of recipes

```
public class Recipe
{
        [Key]
        public int RecipeId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public bool IsCompanyRecipe { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to return all the categories including only recipes that have the **IsCompanyRecipe** marked as **true** using Lambda expression in C#

So far I've got this

```
var query = categories.Where(c => c.Recipes.Count > 0).SelectMany(r => r.Recipes.Where(re => re.IsCompanyRecipe == true));
```

which returns an `IEnumerable<Recipe>` list of all the company recipes but I want to return an `IEnumerable<Category>` list including all the recipes where `IsCompanyRecipe == true`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var query = (from c in categories
         from r in c.Recipes
         where r.IsCompanyRecipe == true
         select c);
```

Comment: You don't need to compare boolean value with true/false

Comment: Although the explicit compare sometimes adds to code readability, e.g. in an example such as this case, or in complex expressions

Comment: Thanks that appears to have done the job. Is it best to write the query like you have rather than Lambda or is it just personal preference

Comment: @dellywheel just preference. I tend to find the way I have wrote the query a little easier to read than using a lambda.